# What's the solution for $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

What's the solution for

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}, n \in \mathbb{N}?$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use this:

$\frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}=a^n \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f(a)\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}$

Show the identity, have some hypothesis of differentiability, and take the limits ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hospital:

$a^nf'(a)-na^{n-1}f(a).$